# C# ContextMenuStrip of DataGridViewRow: what is the equivalent of SourceControl?

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenustrip

Edit 3: It became evident that `RowTemplate.ContextMenuStrip` is not designed to be used by any sane programmer. In addition to all the problems described below, the context menu generated for each row is the clone of the original - but **only to the first level**. Any submenus will **not** appear in the context menu. And apparently it also causes [memory leak](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767830/datagridview-rowtemplate-contextmenustrip-memory-leaks). The moral of the story: don't use `RowTemplate.ContextMenuStrip` ever.

So I thought I figured out the "correct" way to display a context menu when the user right clicks on any row of a `DataGridView`, but not when the user right clicks on the blank area inside the `DataGridView`:

[image: Setting ContextMenuStrip for Row]

By setting the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the `RowTemplate` of the `DataGridView`, I can easily attach a context menu to each of the rows of the `DataGridView`. However, when showing the context menu, I need to know *which* row is right clicked. Normally the way to know where the context menu comes from is using the `ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl` property, but in this case that property only returns the `DataGridView` because, obviously, a `DataGridViewRow` is not a control. So how could I know which row is right clicked?

Edit: I found out that when assigning context menus to rows this way, each row actually has a *clone* of the same `ContextMenuStrip`. That means that we can set the `Tag` property of each `ContextMenuStrip` to the corresponding `DataGridViewRow`. However I don't know if this is inefficient, and if this will cause other unseen problem.

Edit 2: I thought the `SourceControl` property returned null, but that was incorrect - I was checking the `SourceControl` property of the original `ContextMenuStrip`, which the `ContextMenuStrip` that was opening is merely a clone of.

Edit 3: See top of the question.

Comment: The row right clicked on is not necessarily the selected one, right?

Comment: It is not if the user didn't select it first.  Consider working off [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702246/17034) to get the row selected on the right-click and display the cms.

Answer (score 0):

You work with "CellMouseEnter".

```
    {
        ...
        dataGridView1.CellMouseEnter += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter);
        menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        mPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    }

    private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(mPoint.X, mPoint.Y);

        Console.WriteLine(hitTestInfo.RowIndex + ", " + hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex);
    }
```